# converting string to boolean and checking Boolean value

Tags: c#, .net

In an Access database, I have a column named `Display` which is of type `Yes/No`. I am fetching a table row and storing it in a string array named `editDrData[]`. Now, I want to check whether it is true or false. I tried the following, but it's not working. What is the right way to do this check?

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(editDrData[15]) == false)
```

Comment: What is the actual strinf value of elements in the array? Is it actual "Yes" and "No" ?

Comment: while storing I am storing boolean values true and false ,

Comment: If they're boolean, why are u storing them in a string array?

Comment: Actually I am storing whole fetched row in that string array,and now i want to compare that particular value,from that array

Comment: Ok and can you give an example of actual string values of the array elements? e.g. in your example is editDrData[15] actually "true" or "false" ?

Comment: editDrData[15]=true,no double quotes

Comment: Can you insert a breakpoint before the statement and check that the element at 15(16) is actually a string which looks like "true" or "false"

Comment: @Durga: If you are storing the value in string array. Then the code you have given should always work. I have also tested it. It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, according to you, array actually holds boolean values, you don't have to do any conversion. Simple

```
if (editDrData[15]) {

}
```

will do the trick. If its indeed strings, this should work;

```
if (editDrData[15] == "True") {

}
```

Comment: but than how I do check whether value is true or false?

Comment: @ Yuriy Galanter its showing me this error when i tried it `Error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool'`

Comment: this worked `if ((editDrData[15] == "True")`Please update your answer

Comment: As @Durga said: She is storing the value in string array. How can one store actual boolean in string array. One can store only string version of boolean like "true". So "if ((editDrData[15])" will not compile.

Comment: @Durga I've updated my answer after confirming content of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a string comparison

```
bool value = editDrData[15] == "Yes";
```

Comment: while storing I am storing boolean values true and false ,and not a string

Comment: @Durga In the answer above, `value` will be `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison for your table row storing YES/NO.

```
bool value;
if (editDrData[15] == "Yes")
{
    value = true;
}
else
{
    value = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I'd say it is something wrong with the formatting of the string or the logic. You'll need to insert a breakpoint to check but if it conforms to the [examples from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx) then the string should convert succesfully... (if you do put a breakpoint in and find out the value at run time then you will get better answers from us)

So if editDrData[15] looks like "true" or "false"(case doesn't matter) then the code you have above will work.

If the string you have at editDrData[15] is actually "Yes" or "No" then you cannot use Convert.Boolean(string); and you will have to put your own logic in like

```
 
if(editDrData[15] == "No")
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in .net if you want to pass string to  Convert.ToBoolean(), it can only be "True" or "False"

Or I think it will throw exception.

Have you check that is the actual value stored in the database as string? If it is not True and False, you cannot do that in this way.

You can just compare the string in this case

e.g.

if (string.Equals(editDrData[15], "YES???", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
}

String.

BTW: would that be better to store that as boolean when importing into the system?

Answer (score 0):

The string must equal (System.Boolean.TrueString) "TRUE" or (System.Boolean.FalseString) "FALSE", to use Convert.ToBoolean(string)
if you are going to use such function all over the project you can override several method and make your own converter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx